# Remove any comma before or after a string?

Tags: php, regex

My string is

```
$string = ",name2,name2,name3,";
```

I want to make it like;

```
$string = "name2,name2,name3";
```

That is, to remove first and last comma from that string, any clue as to how to accomplish this either through regex or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you just want to remove the first and the last comma, you can use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$string = trim($string,",");
```

Comment: Thanks @coder for the suggestion on the usage of `trim`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^,|,$/', '', $subject);
```

If you want to match one or more commas at the start/end of the string:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^,+|,+$/', '', $subject);
```

And if there could be whitespace around those leading/trailing commas:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[,\s]+|[\s,]+$/', '', $subject);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I didn't used your method but looks like you've got the point too. Unfortunately I've to pick only one answer as best.

Thanks every one! :)